# How to get the commerce subscription status for current user on particular product page?

Tags: notifications, commerce

How can I get the product subscription status for current logged in user on particular product page. Suppose user can subscribe for a video tutorial and we have video as a product then how can we know that current user had already subscribed to this product or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually in thought of adding comment to your question, but my reputation count made me convert my comment to answer. (Yes, I'm a beginner!)

**For your question:**
You have multiple products in your page and there exists a distinct 'commerce sp time' per product. So, the process flow would be,

When an end user subscribes to a particular product:

1. Disable the subscribe button of that product (may be a video tutorial) and change its value to 'subscribed'.
2. Set a schedule for the user with respect to 'commerce sp time' of that product, to trigger a custom PHP code (probably, enabling the susbcription button of that product).

*All my concern is, Is this useful?* 
*I had already achieved this feat technically, so would you..*